# BatchUpdateException updateCounts return inconsistent results

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to find the way to recognise the item that failed in a batch insert using SQL Server (driver: sqljdbc4).

I created a tiny test case that sends a varchar out of range so I got

> "java.sql.BatchUpdateException: String or binary data would be truncated."

I cannot understand the value of `updateCounts`, which is as follows:

When the first batch insert causes error : 
=> updateCounts is -3

When the 2nd batch insert causes error : 
=> Update counts: -3, 1, 1, 1

When the 3rd batch insert causes error : 
=> Update counts: 1, -3, 1, 1

When the 4rd batch insert causes error : 
=> Update counts: 1, 1, -3, 1

When the 5th batch insert causes error : 
=> Update counts: 1, 1, 1, -3

I am sending 5 items all the time, so I was expecting 5 items in `updateCounts`.

Does anyone see a pattern here so I can identify the wrong item?

Comment: please post your code which causes the error

Comment: How are you checking the contents of updateCounts?

Comment: ....} catch (BatchUpdateException bue) {
    updateCounts = bue.getUpdateCounts();.........}